# Error fetching mail in IMAP when space in password

Tags: php, imap

I've a function in IMAP as below which throws an error `The IMAP server did not accept the username and/or password` when $password have a space in it.

```
public function authenticate( $user, $password )
{
    if ( $this->state != self::STATE_NOT_AUTHENTICATED )
    {
        throw new ezcMailTransportException( "Tried to authenticate when there was no connection or when already authenticated." );
    }

    $tag = $this->getNextTag();
    $this->connection->sendData( "{$tag} LOGIN {$user} {$password}" );
    $response = trim( $this->connection->getLine() );
    // hack for gmail, to fix issue #15837: imap.google.com (google gmail) changed IMAP response
    if ( $this->serverType === self::SERVER_GIMAP && strpos( $response, "* CAPABILITY" ) === 0 )
    {
        $response = trim( $this->connection->getLine() );
    }
    if ( strpos( $response, '* OK' ) !== false )
    {
        // the server is busy waiting for authentication process to
        // respond, so it is a good idea to just close the connection,
        // otherwise the application will be halted until the server
        // recovers
        $this->connection->close();
        $this->connection = null;
        $this->state = self::STATE_NOT_CONNECTED;
        return false;
    }
    if ( $this->responseType( $response ) != self::RESPONSE_OK )
    {
        throw new ezcMailTransportException( "The IMAP server did not accept the username and/or password: {$response}." );
    }
    else
    {
        $this->state = self::STATE_AUTHENTICATED;
        $this->selectedMailbox = null;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I've tried all the method of `str_replace()`, adding quuotes or slashes with addslashes() function. But everytime it results into the same error.

echo $response gives `A0001 BAD [CLIENTBUG] Invalid command or arguments`

Any hints/ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $this->connection->sendData( "{$tag} LOGIN {$user} {$password}" );

Put quotes around the password.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But no luck. I tried to put the quotes like this `$this->connection->sendData( "{$tag} LOGIN {$user} '{$password}'" );`. Any other way I could make this work ?

Comment: Use double quotes not single ones.  Don't forget to escape them since they are within a quoted string already.